# Deploying a WebAPI project with several webjobs in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, deployment, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use Azure Devops to do CI/CD. I have created the appropriate Git triggers to build when I push and I create a new release whenever I have produced a new build.

In the release tab I am trying to deploy a WebAPI project with several webjobs using the "Deploy Azure App Service" template. All the logs seem to indicate everything goes fine, but in the end I have nothing when I check the app service in Azure!

I have tried many different configurations and even a few more templates. They all seem fine according to the logs, but nothing is actually ever deployed!

If I try to build/deploy from VS2017 it works beautifully!

**QUESTION**

- what do I need to do in order to successfully deploy my code via Azure Devops

.

My build YAML file is fairly close to the default, only added the CopyFiles@2 due to another SO post suggesting it:

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - slot*
  branches:
    include:
    - dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

name: $(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'    

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  condition: succeeded() #and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Second step I create a release from the artifacts produced via the YAML file.

[image: Azure deployment pipeline]

[image: Azure deployment pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line in your package or folder option

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\*.*
```

It will make sure to pick all the files while deploying.

Also please refer to these ways to deploy webjob to azure:

1. Modify Visual Studio Build task to deploy webjob with FileSystem (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\WebJob" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish)`
2. Add Delete Files task to release definition to delete bin folder (Source Folder: 
   $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WebJobVnext/drop/WebJob); Contents:bin)
3. Modify Azure App Service Deploy task (

   1. Uncheck Publish using Web Deploy option.
   2. Package or folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[artifact name] 
      /drop/WebJob)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, no idea how I would have gotten to what you are suggesting by myself! I am confused about your first suggestion of setting "package or folder" option and your 3.2 point. Should both paths be set? or just one of them?

Comment: to be specific folder , you can use $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[artifact name] /drop/WebJob and fopr all the folder under default working director you can use  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\*.* . You can use it as per your need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I unfortunately do not understand how I can do this. I have found one place to set the directory, how would I set $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[artifact name] /drop/WebJob for Package and Folder and also  use $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)*.* for all folders under default working directory?

Comment: Use only one, whichever suits your need. Most appropriate would be till your $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[artifact name] /drop folder as it would contain all your artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your deploy task.

1. As [Mohit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55333808/2436737) said, you need to specify the zip file of the web project you want to deploy, not just the directory it is in.
2. You need to uncheck "Exclude files from the App_Data folder". This will prevent webjobs from deploying with the website

   2.1 If you haven't, in Visual Studio, you need to right click your web project Add > Existing Project as Azure Webjob. Do this for every webjob project so it will package the webjobs with the website